# Swap Characters, first and last

Tags: java, character, swap

How could I swap the first three letters of a string with the last three?

Would I need to use indexOf or something similar? I'm a java newbie, and would love some help. Thanks.

Comment: Please make an attempt before asking us to do your homework. Come back with a concrete problem.

Comment: @user3072276 - this question is off-topic: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: What is considered similar to `indexOf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String swap (String entry){

    char[] characters = entry.toCharArray();

    if (entry.length() < 6){
        return null; // cannot swap if length is under 6!
    }

    char tempchar;

    tempchar = characters[0];
    characters[0] = characters[characters.length-1];
    characters[characters.length-1] = tempchar;

    tempchar = characters[1];
    characters[1] = characters[characters.length-2];
    characters[characters.length-2] = tempchar;

    tempchar = characters[2];
    characters[2] = characters[characters.length-3];
    characters[characters.length-3] = tempchar;

    return String.copyValueOf(characters);
}
```